# Pass multiple tests names in "dotnet test --filter" option

Tags: .net-core, nunit, dotnet-test

I am trying to rerun failed tests using dotnet test command. I want to pass a list of failed tests from a file created during test run. I can't seem to get the '&' operator syntax right for the "--filter" option. I am able to pass only one test name per run.
Example:
`dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~TestOne1 & FullyQualifiedName~TestOne2"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think of the text you write into the filter like evaluating a boolean. None of your tests' `FullyQualifiedName` can be `TestOne1` AND `TestOne2` at the same time.

Try using the `|` (OR) operator instead like this:

`dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~TestOne1 | FullyQualifiedName~TestOne2"`

This way your test's `FullyQualifiedName` can be like `TestOne1` OR `TestOne2`.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#filter-option-details